# How to set up file permissions for shared computing

Tags: shell-script, permissions

## What is it?

I have set up my own job queuing system which works fine. A user can enter the number of cores (threads) they want to use and the maximum time after which their program will be sigkilled. The queue-system communicates via files. In particular, the following executables and files exist:

## Files

```
root jobq     0 Jun 29 10:53 .commands
root jobq 45591 Jun 29 10:52 log.txt
root jobq     0 Jun 29 10:53 .queue
root jobq    48 Jun 29 10:52 .status
root jobq    30 Jun 28 08:40 .system_buffer
```

## Executables

```
root jobq    52 Jun 22 08:36 .jobq_exec
root jobq 1100896 Jun 22 08:36 jobq_server
root jobq     271 Jun 22 08:36 jobq_server_start
root jobq  364072 Jun 22 08:36 jobq_server_stop
root jobq  363928 Jun 22 08:36 jobq_status
root jobq  368112 Jun 22 08:36 jobq_stop
root jobq  372512 Jun 22 08:36 jobq_submit
```

## The way it works:

`jobq_server_start` is a simple shell script, that checks if a process with name jobq_server is running, and if not, will try to start it.

`jobq_server_stop` will write to the `.commands` file.

`jobq_status` will write to the `.commands` file and read from the `.status` file.

`jobq_submit` will write to the .queue file.

`.jobq_exec` is a shell script that will start a job via `taskset`, which is passed by command line argument and redirects the outputs

`.jobq_stop` will write to the `.commands` file

`jobq_server` is a binary file, that will read and write to `.commands`, `log.txt`, `.queue`, `.status` and `.system_buffer`.

## Question

Currently everything is used by one user (`jobq`), which is shared by different people. I'd like to set up file restrictions, so that

- each user can only run the `jobq_submit`, `jobq_status` and `jobq_stop` commands as themselves (so they need to login as for example `johndoe`, not as `jobq`). If possible, they should not be allowed to edit the text files directly (`.commands`, `.queue`).
- each job will start as the user who submitted it (and as such, can only stop jobs that they started). This will presumably mean that the `.job_exec` script needs to be altered (see below), to switch to the user. I assume this also means that the server can only be started as root, which is fine.

## Script Info

.jobq_exec

```
#!/bin/bash
cd $1
$5 1> $2 2> $3 &
echo $! > $4 2>&1
```

usage (this is executed by the server binary)

```
.job_exec 1:working_directory 2:out_file 3:err_file 4:buffer_file 5:'taskset -ac 1,2,3,4 command cmd_args...'
```

(added argument numbers for clarity)

## Additional info

I'm running Linux Mint 20.3 Una

```
uname -r
5.4.0-105-generic
```

Comment: You will want to quote the variables in that script in case any of the file names or paths contain spaces or globbing characters. See [Why does my shell script choke on whitespace or other special characters?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/131766). Also, please [edit] your question and tell us what operating system this will be used on.

Comment: There are so many good free job queuing systems... slurm, pbs, sge, etc..  why write one?

Comment: @user10489 Because I tried three days to install pbs and it wouldn't work. Even their support couldn't get it running. So, I wrote it as a simple tool / excercise. Even with testing/bug fixing this took only 1/3 of the time I tried to get pbs to work.

Comment: What about (like other job queing daemons I am thinking of cups in particular) creating a special group let's say jobq, set desired permissions to that group (x for jobq_submit, jobq_status and jobq_stop) and have entitled user members of that group ?

Comment: @infinitezero I suggest trying again with [slurm](http://slurm.schedmd.com). In my experience, it's a lot easier to get up and running than pbs, and just works.   if you're used to pbs/torque style commands, it even has a torque compatibility package so you can run qsub, qhold, qdel, qstat, etc as well as slurm's own sbatch, sstat, sinfo, etc commands.    See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_cluster_software for more alternatives, incl. several with free software licenses.

Comment: pbs and sge are common but they both suck and are dated.  Try slurm, it sucks less and is relatively easy to set up.